# Get request working in guzzle but not in curl

Tags: php, api, curl

I am working on an API where I have to get an eBay login page in response.

With guzzle my code is working fine and getting eBay login page Html in response but not if send a request with Curl. In the case of curl I am getting an empty string

```
$query = array(
    'client_id' => 'TestTest-Test-Test-12345678-12345678',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'redirect_uri' => 'Test-redirect-uri',
    'scope' => 'https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.item',
    'prompt' => 'login',
);

$link = "https://auth.sandbox.ebay.com/oauth2/authorize?".http_build_query($query);
```

My curl request

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$output = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
echo $output;
```

My Guzzle request

```
try {
    $response = $client->request('GET', $link);
    echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd($e);
}
```

I have tried lots of solution for curl but i am unable to figure it out why i am getting an empty response in Curl.

Comment: Does https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php help ?

Comment: No i am not getting error. Curl request is successfful just not getting any response.

Comment: Maybe try this option : [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php). You also can use `CURLOPT_HEADER` to see what is the status of the response.

Comment: after curl_exec you may have something like $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); - this is the response code you get from the request, along with CURLOPT_HEADER you can understand what's the problem

Comment: @Syscall  first i added CURLOPT_HEADER. i saw a 303 response is added. then i added CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.. that worked fine.. you may add it to answer so that people will get help of it... generally people dont see the comments.  Thanks

Comment: For information, a 303 response is [`303 See Other`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303), a _" redirect status response code"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response probably contains a redirection.

You can add the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) option, to allow cURL to follow the `Location:`  header.

```
$handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Allows to follow redirections
$output = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
```

Comment: This answer worked  for me. There was a redirect header in the response. adding curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true) redirected me to ebay login page. Thanks buddy.